# finding points on curve $x^2y^2=16$ that are closest to origin in two ways

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

(a)  by finding the minimum value of an appropriate function of one variable

(b)  by using the method of Lagrange multipliers.

so from what I understand, for part (a) I can use the equation that $x^2y^2=16$ and write $y$ in terms of $x$ in the equation $x^2+y^2$. After that, I will find the gradient to find critical points and use the Hessian matrix to determine the type of extremum.

And for part (b), let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g(x,y)=x^2y^2$ and then

$\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ and solve the equations.

Am I on the right path?

Edit:- So I solved the answer through the first method and I have found the critical points through Lagrange multipliers method. But how do I write the Hessian matrix to prove that those critical points are minimal?
I am having trouble understanding it. I only know that the first element should be 0 and other elements of the first row and column should be $[-2xy^2\ -2x^2y]$. I can't proceed from there.

Comment: @amd I'm sorry, I didn't even notice that I equated it to zero.

Answer (score 1):

For (b) you are on the right path.

For (a): we have $y^2=\frac{16}{x^2}$, hence $x^2+y^2=x^2+\frac{16}{x^2}$.

Therefore you have to minimize the function $g(x):= x^2+\frac{16}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

An option:

Want to minimize $x^2+y^2$:

(Note : This is the distance$^2$, easier to handle).

Let $x,y >0$, i.e. the first quadrant.

$x^2+y^2 = (x-y)^2 +2xy =(x-y)^2 + (2)4.$

Minimum : $x=y$.

$2x^2= (2)(4)$, or $x=2$, and $y=2$.

Considering the invariance of the problem under

$x \rightarrow -x$, and $y \rightarrow -y$ ,

you get the remaining $(x,y)$ coordinates.